# Send the request over and over again until I get the expected value in the body of the response at postman

Tags: url, postman

Send the request over and over again until I get the expected value in the body of the reply

I have two chained request:
In the first request, I send a parameter in the URL,
and expect to receive in the response a unique string value
this string value that I get from the first response I send as a parameter at a second request
in the second response is expected to receive a string value: "done", assigned at the status property
if actually receive as string value the string "in-process" the postman should send the same request over and over again until I get the expected string value "in process" in the body response at the postman

Answer (score 0):

```
 let jsonData = pm.response.json();
let val = jsonData.status
if (val === "in process") {
    postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName)
}
```

This will send the current reqeust multiple time if status property value is "in process"